# Cannot find symbol between classes

Tags: java, class, nodes

I am making a program to create a Huffman tree.  When I get to line 31 (node[i] = setFreq(freq);), my compiler returning an error "cannot find symbol", symbol being "method setFreq(int)" and location being "class Huffman".  As far as I can tell node[i] is initializing properly as NodeType, but not going back to the class the line mentioned.  Below is section of my code that should be all that is necessary (apologies if it isn't). The input table is going to be line-after-line of letter-frequency, ie: 
A-3
B-32
C-23
etc.
Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Huffman{
    final static int MAXBITS = 138;
    final static int MAXSYMBS = 138;
    final static int MAXNODES = 255;

    public static void Huffman(){
       CodeType cd = new CodeType();
       CodeType code[] = new CodeType[MAXSYMBS];
       NodeType node[] = new NodeType[MAXNODES];
       int i, k, p, o, q, root, freq;
       DynamicList rootNodes = new DynamicList();
       char symb;
       char alph[] = new char[MAXSYMBS];

       for (i=0; i<MAXSYMBS; i++){
           alph[i] = ' ';
       }

       try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("HuffmanTable.txt"))){
          String line;
          i=0;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
              String[] parts = line.split("-");
              node[i] = new NodeType();
              String trick = parts[0];
              symb = trick.charAt(0);
              freq = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
              node[i] = setFreq(freq);
              rootNodes.pqInsert(new SmallNode(i, freq));
              alph[i] = symb;
              i++;
         }
   }
}
```

And the NodeType class

```
public class NodeType{
    private int freq;
    private int father;
    private boolean isLeft;

    public NodeType(){}

    public void isLeft(boolean fact){
        isLeft = fact;
    }
    public boolean isLeft(){
        return isLeft;
    }
    public void setFreq(int fr){
        freq = fr;
    }
    public int getFreq(){
        return freq;
    }
    public void setFather(int fath){
        father = fath;
    }
    public int getFather(){
        return father;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `setFreq(int)` is the instance method of `NodeType` class. Besides that, is doesn't return a `NodeType` object so you cannot assign it like that to `node[i]`.

What you need to do is create `NodeType` object, initialize it with values you need and then put it into array.

```
NodeType node = new NodeType();
node.setFreq( freq );
node[i] = node;
```